# Unable to clear cache

Tags: caching

I am facing an severe issue with Drupal instance. I am trying to clear the cache and the page is redirecting to error page.

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Please help.

Comment: Check the web server error log.

Comment: I checked the apache and php error log. no errors.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Check errors in your browser console. Try to fix the errors first. The cache might not be functioning well because of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Either drush cc or manually truncate cache tables in the db (Backup first!). Unsure if you are running Varnish, but if so you may want to manually flush this as well.